How to make PyQGIS to return 4 raster subdivisions calculated by inequations
I've been making in Raster Calculator, one by one, for every Return Period (2, 5, 10, 50, etc.) different sub-rasters of 4 sections of water depth, it's very tedious and I know there is a faster way to do this in Python. Let's say those intervals are:

depth <0.2 m
0.2 m <= depth <0.3 m
0.3 m <= depth <0.5 m
0.5 m => depth

For every RP.
I would like a script that gives me those four intervals as raster outputs in one particular PR, but so far, I can't get QgsRasterCalculator to work with those inequations. Any direction and/or guidance into this? im very new to Python in QGIS and all the information available seems outdated or very cryptic.

I'm answering this question because it is necessary to increase the information about the use of Raster Calculator in PyQGIS (QgsRasterCalculator and QgsRasterCalculatorEntry classes and methods). Its use is easier than other alternate methods (as gdal_translate and processing tools) employed in other answers avoiding the explicit employ of Raster Calculator saying that it is difficult to use and understand.
Probably, the critical path is to find out the correct expression because normally the code runs without any apparent error (because it is not printed the important code result). Other issues are related with the correct use of QgsRasterCalculatorEntry methods.
Considering above question, I created and arbitrary raster layer with not integer values between 0 and 1; 0.1, 0.2, ..., 1.0). This raster was used for classifying the above considered intervals in 4 different classes by using an expression with nested if statements. It was contemplated in following code:
main_path = '/home/zeito/Desktop/test4/'

lyr1 = QgsRasterLayer(main_path + "c.tif", "c")

output = main_path + "testing2.tif"

entries = []

ras = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
ras.ref = 'ras@1'
ras.raster = lyr1
ras.bandNumber = 1
entries.append(ras)

expression = 'if(ras@1 <= 0.2, 1, \
              if(ras@1 > 0.2 and ras@1 <= 0.3, 2, \
              if(ras@1 > 0.3 and ras@1 <= 0.5, 3, \
              if(ras@1 > 0.5, 4, 0))))'

print(expression)

calc = QgsRasterCalculator(expression, 
                           output, 
                           'GTiff',
                           lyr1.extent(), 
                           lyr1.width(), 
                           lyr1.height(), 
                           entries)

calc.processCalculation()

After running above code in Python Console of QGIS, loaded layer was obtained as expected: four classes (1, 2, 3 and 4) according considered intervals.

